# `bundle install` and got message error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I new rails framework  `bundle install` and got message

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:81:in `parse': Illformed requirement ["1.6.3.1 ruby java x64-mingw32 x86-mingw32"] (ArgumentError)
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:106:in `block in initialize'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:106:in `map!'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:106:in `initialize'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:44:in `new'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:44:in `create'
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:50:in `initialize'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dependency.rb:31:in `initialize'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:75:in `new'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:75:in `gem'
   /home/kn3l/workspace/railsprojects/mongkhut/Gemfile:40:in `eval_gemfile'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:30:in `instance_eval'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:30:in `eval_gemfile'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:9:in `evaluate'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:19:in `build'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:245:in `install'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
   /usr/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <main>'
   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
   /usr/bin/bundle:20:in `<main>'
```

My `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.3.1 ruby java x64-mingw32 x86-mingw32'
```

There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.

How can I fixed this issue?

Comment: Posting your Gemfile would be a good start

Comment: Yes please check my updating.

Comment: It may be that you need to update to the newest version of Rubygems. That's fixed similar issues for me with other gems in the past.

Answer (score 2):

This line:
`gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.3.1 ruby java x64-mingw32 x86-mingw32'`
makes bundler look for nokogiri with the version "1.6.3.1 ruby java x64-mingw32 x86-mingw32", which is not a valid version.

I'm guessing you want version "1.6.3.1", on the platforms ruby, java, x64-mingw32 and x86-mingw32, which would be specified as `gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.3.1', platforms: %i(ruby java x64-mingw32 x86-mingw32)`.

Adding to that, java, x64-mingw32 and x86-mingw32 are not valid platforms, do you mean jruby and mingw respectively?